# \shortstack in \newcolumntype

Tags: tables, columns

I want to have a column type where to every cell a certain text is added.

I was thinking of using:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\shortstack\bgroup extratext\\}c<{\egroup}}
```

I expected this would would give me the desired result but it complains about missing } and {. An explanation why this happens would be greatly appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\shortstack\bgroup extratext\\}c<{\egroup}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{CCC}
        a & b & c
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\shortstack` doesn't allow its argument to be between `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (only a few macros do, because they're based on primitives, but this behavior is very particular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify the argument to `\shortstack` by enclosing it between `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. In some cases this works or seems to, but just by chance.

With `collcell` you can do it: if you declare `\usepackage{collcell}`, the syntax is

```
>{\collectcell\macro}c<{\endcollectcell}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,collcell}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\extratext}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcommand{\extratext}[1]{\shortstack{extratext\\#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CCC}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]